# Uninstalling PHP 8.0 that was installed through Web Platform Installer

Tags: php, windows

I am trying to uninstall PHP 8.0 (x64) on a windows server 2022 machine. I have tried all methods available but WPI still detects it as installed.

What I have tried so far :

- Deleting the folders relating to PHP
- Uninstalling PHP through apps and features
- Found somewhere that you have to delete the file from an IIS Express folder which I don't have it .
- Went into applicationHost.config there is no trace of php there.

Comment: Have you modified the system environmental variable?

Comment: Yup, nothing found related to php

Comment: Can you provide us more specifics on how you are detecting the PHP installation itself?

Comment: Well for some reason WPI still does detect it. Worth to mention I am total newbie to this stuff

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reconfigured the IIS and it works. Probably a conflict or error occurred during the install.